# Extract the last row of list in Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, invoke-restmethod

I'm using Powershell to extract data via an API. For some reason, the output is providing multiple rows of data, however I'm only interested in the last row.

As this data is already filtered using

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest "HTTP://xyz.xyz"
$lines = $r.Content.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
$lines | Select-String 'alpha
```

'

What should I add in this command to grep the last line

How can I filter the last line from the data below

```
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.522.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.522.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.524.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.524.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.528.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.528.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.531.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.531.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.533.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.533.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.536.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.536.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.540.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.540.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.543.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.543.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.547.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.547.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.552.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.552.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.556.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.556.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.558.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.558.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.560.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.560.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.562.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.562.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.564.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.564.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.568.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.568.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.570.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.570.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.572.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.572.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.574.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.574.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.578.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.578.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.602.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.602.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.605.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.605.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.607.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.607.tar.gz</a></li>
<li><a href="7.1.0-alpha.616.tar.gz"> 7.1.0-alpha.616.tar.gz</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines | Select-String 'alpha' | Select -Last 1
```